# Firebase listeners when offline and not authenticated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is this behavior correct?

I'm using firebase as local database, and also  for (optional) authentication and (optional) sync.

When a user hasn't authenticated yet, and I set  .goOffline(), the ValueEventListener (either with and ValueEventListener or addListenerForSingleValueEvent)  never gets called when I try adding stuff (locally, because I am always offline). Note that the ChildEventListener does get called in this case.

If the user authenticates, and I still set goOffline(), the ValueEventListener and the ChildEventListener both get called correctly, as expected.

I am wondering why this happens (only ChildEventListener getting called when not authenticated), and wouldn't mind any clarification if I'm doing something wrong.

Secondly, is the local cache a database or does it only store a list of transactions? In other words, if I always stay offline, will firebase have to go through thousands of transactions history to deliver what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: For you first part, can you replace the description of what your code does with the actual [minimum code that reproduces the behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That'll be easier to parse for most of us here. For your second question: the Firebase Database is primarily an online database, that also handles intermittent and medium term lack of connectivity.